# Search query for prefix

Tags: php, mysql, sql, jquery

I'm trying to create a query for my website where the user will type in his cellphone number and the page will search the DB (I'm using MYSQL) to find the possible carrier. So far I tried something like this,

> "Select Carrier_name from Carrier_info where prefix like 'prefix%' "

My Carrier_info table:

```
====   ============  ======
ID     carrier_name  prefix
====   ============ =======
1        A           88017
2        B           88019
3        C           91
4        D           8801
```

The problem is that when I search a number like 880171...... it gives me no result. So, I tried searching with only the first 5 digits which partially worked. But since the prefix table has different number digits like 88017,91,8801 it creates a problem and I cannot specifically fix the search with first 5 digits.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to search the first 5, or can you select the whole prefix like %prefix%?

Comment: Yes and no. I need to search the first x number of digits. the problem is that x is not fixed.It can be first 5 or first 2. And %prefix% I think will not work for me. The users will input something like this XXXXXXXXXXXXXX and I need to use these 11-15 digits to figure out which one it matches with my DB. With my current DB the highest number of digits in a single prefix row is 5. I can assume that I will not search more than first 5 digits.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

```
SELECT Carrier_name FROM Carrier_info WHERE '880171' LIKE CONCAT(`prefix`,"%")
```

In the above query `prefix` is the field name and you can replace `880171` with any numbers you want to search.